# Problem related to conditional independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Question: Show that if $A$ and $B$ are independent and $C = A \cup B$, then $A$ and $B$ are conditionally dependent given $C$ (so as long as $\mathbb{P} ( A \cap B ) > 0$ and $\mathbb{P} ( A \cup B) < 1)$, with:
$\mathbb{P}(A|B,C) < \mathbb{P}(A|C)$. So basically we have to prove that $\mathbb{P}(A,B|C) \neq \mathbb{P}(A|C) \mathbb{P}(B|C)$.

I have tried proving this but am falling short at expanding the formula.

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far. Otherwise we can't help you, where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

You have to show $$ P(A\cap B\mid C) < P(A\mid C)P(B\mid C).$$

You need to use the fact that $C = A\cup B$ and the best way to proceed is to use the definition of conditional probability and then some set identities / venn diagrams. For instance $$ P(A\cap B\mid A\cup B) = \frac{P((A\cap B)\cap (A\cup B))}{P(A\cup B)} = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A\cup B)} = \frac{P(A)P(B)}{P(A\cup B)}$$ where we used the fact that $A\cap B\subseteq A\cup B$ and the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Using the same approach on both factors on the RHS should give you something you can work with.

Answer (score 0):

LHS = \begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[A,B|C] &= \frac{\mathbb{P}[(A, B), C]}{\mathbb{P}[C]} \\
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}[A , B]}{\mathbb{P}[C]} \\
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}[A] \cdot \mathbb{P}[B]}{\mathbb{P}[C]} \\
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}[A] \cdot \mathbb{P}[B]}{\mathbb{P}[C]}
\end{align}

RHS = \begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[A|C] \cdot \mathbb{P}[B|C] &= \frac{\mathbb{P}[A, C]}{\mathbb{P}[C]} \cdot \frac{\mathbb{P}[B, C]}{\mathbb{P}[C]} \\
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}[A]}{\mathbb{P}[C]} \cdot \frac{\mathbb{P}[B]}{\mathbb{P}[C]}
\end{align}

This proves conditional Independence, i.e. what you said after "Basically".

To prove $\mathbb{P}[A|B,C] < \mathbb{P}[A|C]$, LHS is

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[A|B,C] &= \frac{\mathbb{P}[A, B, C]}{\mathbb{P}[B, C]} \\
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}[A, B]}{\mathbb{P}[B]} \\
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}[A] \cdot \mathbb{P}[B]}{\mathbb{P}[B]}
&= \mathbb{P}[A]
\end{align}

RHS is $\mathbb{P}[A|C] = \frac{\mathbb{P}[A, C]}{\mathbb{P}[C]} = \frac{\mathbb{P}[A]}{\mathbb{P}[C]}$. Since $\mathbb{P}[C] < 1$, LHS < RHS.